# Is sending redundant data over websocket over HTTP/2 practically free?

Tags: websocket, compression, http2

I'm writing a web app feature that would use WebSocket messages to transmit JSON structures between client and server. The most simple protocol for the app would be to keep repeatedly sending mostly redudant parts back and forth. **Can HTTP/2 compression effectively compress redundant parts in separate messages going back and forth?** I know this should be possible in theory but how about in practice?

**Example case:**

Assume that the `shared_state` is a string that is *mostly* same but not identical between different messages:

Client connects:

`ws = new WebSocket("wss://myserver.example/foo/bar");`

Client sends message over the WebSocket connection:

`{ command: "foo", shared_state: "...long data here..." }`

Server sends:

`{ command: "bar", shared_state: "...long data here slightly modified..." }`

Client sends:

`{ command: "zoo", shared_state: "...long data here slightly modified again..." }`

All these messages will be passed over a single HTTP/2 connection using a single websocket.

Will the messages going in both directions be compressed by HTTP/2? This would mean that the later data packets effectively could just use some references to already seen data in previously transmitted data in the same HTTP/2 connection. It would simplify the custom protocol that I need to implement if I can keep sending the shared state instead of just delta without causing high bandwidth usage in practice. I don't need to care about old clients that cannot support HTTP/2.

I'm assuming the delta between messages to be less than 1 KB but the whole message including the redundant part could be usually in range 10-60 KB.

Comment: Note that running WebSocket over HTTP/2 requires browser to support RFC 8441: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8441

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way WebSocket over HTTP/2 works is that WebSocket frames are carried as opaque bytes in HTTP/2 `DATA` frames.
A logical WebSocket connection is carried by a single HTTP/2 stream, with "infinite" request content and "infinite" response content, as `DATA` frames (containing WebSocket frames) continue to flow from client to server and from server to client.

Since WebSocket bytes are carried by `DATA` frames, there is no "compression" going on at the HTTP/2 level.

HTTP/2 only offers "compression" for HTTP headers via HPACK in `HEADERS` frames, but WebSocket over HTTP/2 cannot leverage that (because it does not use HTTP/2 `HEADERS` frames).

Your custom protocol has key/value pairs, but it's a WebSocket payload carried by `DATA` frames.

The only "compression" that you're going to get is driven by WebSocket's permessage-deflate functionality.

For example, a browser would open a connection, establish WebSocket over HTTP/2 (with the permessage-deflate extension negotiated during WebSocket upgrade), and then send a WebSocket message. The WebSocket message will be compressed, the compressed bytes packed into WebSocket frames, the WebSocket frames packed in HTTP/2 `DATA` frames and then sent over the network.

If your `shared_state` compresses well, then you are trading network bandwidth (less bytes over the network) for CPU usage (to decompress).
If it does not compress well, then it's probably not worth it.

I'd recommend that you look into existing protocols over WebSocket, there may be ones that do what you need already (for example, [Bayeux](https://docs.cometd.org/current/reference/#_bayeux)).

Also, consider not using JSON as format since now JavaScript supports binary, so you may be more efficient (see for example [CBOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CBOR)).

Comment: Great info! I think my `shared_state` would compress very effectively only when the compression can refer to *previous message* in the same channel. Compressing just a single message as standalone will not be nearly as effective. I guess I'll need to use more complex protocol  or find some existing library to support my specific use case. The library called `fflate` seems to support stream compression – I might be able to use that over multiple messages to get the compression I'm looking for unless I find some more suitable library for the task.

Comment: And **TL;DR:** Sending redundant data over WebSocket over HTTP/2 is not practically free.